# Which folders or files i need to transfer Gwt compile outputs into phonegap" www" folder?

Tags: gwt, cordova

Which folders or files i need to transfer to work fine in phonegap. I succeed in GWT but the problem is :I only transfer "war" folder in GWT into Phonegap's "www" folder. And it did not work as in GWT. (i guess javascript applications does not work). My project was default GWT first tutorial.
Anyway, is there a any way first create in GWT and run applications in phonegap platform?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your GWT Applications just fine in phonegap ( take a look at http://www.m-gwt.com ). This open source project is all about running mobile gwt.

Basically what you need to do is copy the GWT output to the www folder of your phonegap project.

lets say your module has the name "greet". Then the gwt compiler is going to create a folder "greet" as its output folder containing all files that you need to run your app.

What you also want to do is change the index.html file from phonegap to include your GWT app.

So somewhere after:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="cordova-version.js"></script>
```

You need to include your gwt module:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="greet/greet.nocache.js"></script>
```

If you want to take a look at http://www.m-gwt.com there is a lot of documentation there on how to get started with GWT / Phonegap.